# Negative Binomial Regression or Poisson Regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

Regarding Generalized Linear Models, at what point do you consider that a Negative Binomial Regression should be used? For example, if the dispersion index is equal to 1.8 (= therefore quite close to 1), should I switch to a Negative Binomial Regression or a Poisson Regression does the trick? Also, Deviance Value/df and Pearson Chi-Square Value/df are respectively equal to 1.52 and 1.82.

Comment: The Poisson quasi-likelihood approach should suffice, but if the dispersion index is statistically different from 1, the negative Binomial approach may be better.  Unfortunately, it is not immediately straightforward to compare an information criterion (AIC, BIC, etc.) from the negative Binomial distribution with a quasiPoisson model, since the latter defines estimating equations, not a likelihood.  But, you can compare the Negative Binomial regression's information criterion with the Poisson regression's information criterion to choose between models.